# How to know if a virtualenv requires a sync in order to avoid running pipenv sync for every job deployed on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv, pipenv, pipfile

I am running Python 3.7 on Jenkins' slaves within a virtualenv that is created from a Pipfile.lock that I store in the project's git.

For every job I deploy on the slave, I need to know if the virtualenv is up-to-date  or requires pipenv sync.

Currently pipenv doesn't provide a method to check if the existing virtualenv matches the Pipfile.lock it relates to.

I am currently using the following scriptology to check for the above, but I am wondering if there is a better\easier\official way to do that.

My method:

```
if virtualenv exists and Pipfile.lock.back exists:
   compare md5sum of Pipfile.lock from project's Git vs. a previous copy Pipfile.lock.bak
   if files are identical:
      skip pipenv sync
      finish
   else:
      perform pipenv sync 
      if sync is successful:
          save a copy of project Git Pipfile.lock as Pipfile.lock.bak
      finish
else:  # virtualenv doesn't exist
   pipenv sync
   if sync is successful:
      save a copy of project Git Pipfile.lock as Pipfile.lock.bak
   finish
```

- Note: This method doesn't handle any issues of virtualenv corruptions.